# Xcode storyboard splash screen for iOS is not scaling properly

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, splash-screen, xcode-storyboard

My app is a Cordova app...most everything I do is compiled from CLI and then in Xcode I verify a few things and then deploy to devices to test.

When deploying my app to real phone or simulator the splash screen is not scaled properly - its distorted.  I have tried all kinds of edits and changes but nothing is correcting the issue.  It sort of looks like its using a landscape version of my splash screen and smooshing it to fit into a portrait view.

In Xcode I verified the following:

1. Device orientation: Portrait
2. LaunchScreen: CDVLaunchScreen (this is a storyboard)
3. Interface Builder Doc:
   x = use trait variations
   x = use safe area layout guides
   x = use as launch screen
4. View -> Content Mode = Scale To Fill

For my config.xml file:

```
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" /> (2732 x 2732)
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~comany.png" /> (1278 x 2732)
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~comcom.png" /> (1334 x 750)
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" /> (2208 x 2208)
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@3x~universal~anycom.png" /> (2208 x 1242)
        <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@3x~universal~comany.png" /> (1242 x 2208)
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="2688" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2688h~iphone.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2688h~iphone.png" width="2688" />
        <splash height="1792" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-1792h~iphone.png" width="828" />
        <splash height="828" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-1792h~iphone.png" width="1792" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
```

I am fresh out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

User error...always is right.  It was 2am when I made the splash images and next day I couldn't figure out what was wrong.  I took a 2732x2732 image and simply resized it to each of the universal sizes...which skewed each image.  I just now corrected all of my images to center my image inside of each of the universal X/Y sizes.

Bonehead move.  Exhaustion will do it to ya.